# ES6 OOP inheriting methods from parent class

Tags: javascript, oop, object, es6-class

I have some simple code:

```
'use strict';

class GameObject {
    constructor(element){
        this.element = element;
}

    render(width,height,color){
        let newEl = document.createElement(this.element);
        newEl.style.width = width;
        newEl.style.height = height;
        newEl.style.backgroundColor = color;
        document.body.appendChild(newEl);
    }
}

class Circle extends GameObject{
    constructor(element){
       super()
        this.element = element;
   }



   //render(){}

}
```

The circle `Class` currently has access to the render method from `GameObjects` I want it to havean added feature of turning the element circular i.e. `elem.style.borderRadius = 50%` however if I add a render method on the `Circle Class` it overwrites the original method. How can I keep the original inherited `render()` method and add a feature to it on a child class? Without having to copy and paste the render method from the parent class?

**Update:**
I have tried using the `super()` method and it throws the following error `index.js:24 Uncaught SyntaxError: 'super' keyword unexpected here`

```
class Circle extends GameObject{
constructor(element){
    super()
    this.element = element;
}

render(){
    super()

   }

}
```

Comment: You mean you can't use `super` in the child implementation?

Comment: If I use `super()` I get this error `Uncaught SyntaxError: 'super' keyword unexpected here`

Comment: Could you give a [mcve] of that? Are you calling `super.render()`?

Comment: @jonrsharpe editted

Comment: That should be `super.render()`, `super()` calls the constructor. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/super

Comment: Ok, I fixed it thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From parent render you can return rendered element. So - in the child class `Circle` you can add additional requried styles …

```js
class GameObject {
  constructor(element) {
    this.element = element;
  }

  render(width, height, color) {
    let newEl = document.createElement(this.element);
    newEl.style.width = width;
    newEl.style.height = height;
    newEl.style.backgroundColor = color;
    document.body.appendChild(newEl);
    return newEl
  }
}

class Circle extends GameObject {
  constructor(element) {
    super(element)
  }
  
  render(width, height, color) {
    let e = super.render(width, height, color)
    e.style.borderRadius = "50%"
  }
}

let c = new Circle('div')
c.render('40px', '40px', '#FF0000')
```

Some modified way with stored new created element.

```js
class GameObject {
  constructor(element) {
    this.element = element;
  }

  render(width, height, color) {
    this.newEl = document.createElement(this.element);
    this.newEl.style.width = width;
    this.newEl.style.height = height;
    this.newEl.style.backgroundColor = color;
    document.body.appendChild(this.newEl);
  }
}

class Circle extends GameObject {
  constructor(element) {
    super(element)
  }
  
  render() {
    super.render(...arguments)
    this.newEl.style.borderRadius = "50%"
  }
}

let c = new Circle('div')
c.render('40px', '40px', '#BB0000')
```

Comment: Is this a traditional way to do it?

Comment: We can modify it more - `render()` method from parent class in way that it will create / store  new created element in instance field. Let me show some code for it

Answer (score 0):

`super()` calls the constructor, for other methods you need to call `super.methodName`; see e.g. [the MDN guide](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/super). In your case:

```
render() {
  super.render()
}
```